# Just added comment shows at different page, but not at the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When Im trying to add a comment at Details page it send to this page:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ED946C8D08765D6F%21107

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Student student = _db.Students.Include(m => m.Comments).SingleOrDefault(x   => x.ID == id);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    //var enrollments = new Enrollment { };

    var model = new DetailsViewModel
    {
        Comment = new Comment(),
        Student = student,
        Comments = student.Comments.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList()
    };
}

public ActionResult AddComment(Comment comment, int commentId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && commentId > 0)
    {
        var commentToAdd = new Comment
        {
            Email = comment.Email,
            CommentId = commentId,
            Name = comment.Name,
            Text = comment.Text,
        };
        _db.Comments.Add(commentToAdd);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("_Comment", commentToAdd);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
}
```

Details View:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.FirstMidName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.FirstMidName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.EnrollmentDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.EnrollmentDate)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.Enrollments)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Course Title</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </dd>
    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Comments</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Student.ID" name="commentId" />

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment.Text)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Text)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div id="comments">
        @foreach (var c in Model.Comments)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Comment", c)
        }
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Student.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

DetailsViewModel:

```
public Student Student { get; set; }
public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
public Comment Comment { get; set; }
```

Comment Model:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public int CommentId { get; set; }
public Student Student { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }

[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Student Model:

```
public int ID { get; set; }

public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

I can't understand what is wrong it was work some time ago. Thank you

Comment: Recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's what you telling it to do with this line

```
return PartialView("_Comment", commentToAdd);
```

If you want to go back to the current page showing the newly added comment, then it should be

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = commentId });
```

and you doing a post so it should be `FormMethod.Post` in the `BeginForm()` method